# Import raster files into Python 3.10

Tags: python, raster

I'm working on a project that requires the python 3.10 version but am having some difficulty accessing the files on that version. These files have the '.tiff' extension and contain metadata information about multispectral bands like resolution, band number, etc. I was able to import the files using the rasterio module in 3.9 version but couldn't get it to work on 3.10 and couldn't find another module perform the task. I would appreciate any advice on this, thanks.

Comment: Question needs some code
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, doing `pip install raster` will attempt to install rasterio-1.2.10, which supports Python 3.6 to 3.9. For Python 3.10 support, you'll need to rasterio 1.3, which is currently in beta. You can install 1.3 beta 3 with `pip install rasterio==1.3b3`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using : pip install whatever_you_want
In the shell. It resets the package and it should work.
like: if you want to install ‘Replit’ just do pip install replit in the command shell

Comment: Hi, I tried that earlier but couldn't get it to work. Using the 'pip install rasterio' installs the package on my 3.9 interpreter, but when I use the 'python3.10 -m pip install rasterio' to identify the specific python version, I get this error: *Failed to build rasterio: ERROR: Could not build wheels for rasterio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects*

Comment: Hmmm then install pyproject?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did that but the rasterio module still gives the same error.